# Bootstrap 4: Why isn't this aligned to the bottom?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a card and in it is an image then a header. Then, I want to have a paragraph and link all of the way at the bottom of the card. I defined a min-height in CSS to make room to do so. However, the following code just flows top to bottom with space at the bottom instead of content there.

```
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card shadow">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x900?house" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">47 Dream Homes You'll Wish You Could Afford</h5>
                        <div class="text-center d-block align-items-end">
                            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos odio possimus labore ratione!.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is what it looks like and I want the lorem ipsum and button to be right up against the bottom with the headline at the top.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest an alternative solution; one that would not require additional CSS and instead rely on Bootstrap's existing framework.  The `.card-footer` class is part of the Card component and can integrate very well with your desired results.

To achieve equal heights you could rely either on `.card-deck` or simply applying the `.h100` class to the `.card` wrapper.  Since it's unclear how you might be applying this design to multiple cards the below example relies on `.h100`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card h-100 shadow">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x900?house" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">47 Dream Homes You'll Wish You Could Afford</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer bg-white border-top-0 text-center">
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos odio possimus labore ratione!.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card h-100 shadow">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x900?house" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">47 Dream Homes You'll Wish You Could Afford</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer bg-white border-top-0 text-center">
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos odio possimus labore ratione! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos odio possimus labore ratione! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos odio possimus labore ratione!</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card h-100 shadow">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x900?house" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">47 Dream Homes You'll Wish You Could Afford</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer bg-white border-top-0 text-center">
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos odio possimus labore ratione! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos odio possimus labore ratione!</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Now by default `.card-footer` applies a top border as well as a slightly darker background.  We can override those styles by applying `.bg-white` to modify the background color and `.border-top-0` to remove the top border.  There is no reason to declare it a block element and centering the text is as simple as applying `.text-center`.

No `min-height` CSS involved.

For more information on how the Card component can be grouped please review [Bootstrap's 4.x documentation on Card layou](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-layout)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the `card-body` a flex-column and then align use a Bootstrap utility class to push the elements to the bottom.

[**Bootstrap Flex Utilities**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

So we apply `.d-flex` and `.flex-column` to the `.card-body` div and `.mt-auto` to the div holding your paragraph and button.

```css
.card {
  height: 600px;
  /* artificial height */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="card shadow">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x900?house" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">47 Dream Homes You'll Wish You Could Afford</h5>
          <div class="text-center d-block mt-auto">
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos odio possimus labore ratione!.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use 
use card groups so that footer section will align to the bottom.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer should provide code to demonstrate the solution you are proposing.