# Container fluid in last tag floating right and scrollbar appear in bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
body{
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 !important;
}
nav .navbar-nav li a{
   color: white !important;
   font-family: "Titillium Web";
  }
nav .navbar-nav li a:hover {
  text-align: center;
     width: 77px;
     height: 32px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     background-color: #643a79
}  
.jumbotron{
 font-size: 42px;
 line-height: 49px;
 color: #f7f3ea;
 font-family: "Titillium Web";
 font-weight: 700;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #87509c;
 margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.welcome-text{
 font-size: 42px;
 line-height: 49px;
 color: #f7f3ea;
 font-family: "Titillium Web";
 font-weight: 700;
 text-align: center;
}
.btn{
 margin-top: 62px;
 width: 293px;
 height: 70px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 background-color: #eb7d4b
}
.btn a{
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 line-height: 26px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "Titillium Web";
 font-weight: 600;
}
.btn a:hover {
 text-align: center;
 color:white; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    cursor:pointer;
}
.services{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #17c2a4;
}
.services h1{
 font-size: 40px;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
 line-height: 30px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "Titillium Web";
 font-weight: 700;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 120px;
}
.services hr{
 width: 87px;
 height: 4px;
 background-color: #60ead2;
}
.services p{
 font-size: 18px;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 line-height: 26px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "Titillium Web";
 font-weight: 400;
 text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.img-box{
 width:200px;
 height: 200px;
 margin-left: 65px;
}

.img-box img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.team h1{
 font-size: 41px;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
 line-height: 30px;
 color: #3c4761;
 font-family: "Titillium Web";
 font-weight: 700;
 text-align: center;
}
.team hr{
 width: 87px;
 height: 4px;
 background-color: #bdd1df;
}
.team p{
 font-size: 18px;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 line-height: 26px;
 color: #3c4761;
 font-family: "Titillium Web";
 font-weight: 400;
 text-align: center;
}
.team{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #e7f1f8;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .services h1, .team h1{
   line-height: 40px;
  }
}
.mugshot{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 background-color: #878787;
}
.team .job {
 font-size: 16px;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 line-height: 18px;
 color: #30bae7;
 font-family: "Titillium Web";
 font-weight: 400;
 text-align: center;
}
.team ul{
 text-align: center;
 list-style: none;
}
.team ul li{
 margin:0 5px;
}

.team .contacts .base:hover{
 background-color: #0BC5FA;
}
.team .contacts .base{
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 border-radius: 16px;
 background-color: #bdd1df;
}
```

So I am new with twitter bootstrap and I am trying to learn and develop my skills. But I have faced a problem a few weeks ago and still can't fix it. 
So here is the problem: I have 2 divs with the class of container-fluid. First one is equal width with Jumbotron but second one(

I tried adding overflow: hidden thing. But this doesn't help because the second div has some gap in the left

And sorry for the long code snippet. This is my second time posting question :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:/use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\bootstrap.css">
    <link href="https:/fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\styles.css">
    <title>Cuda Website</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #87509c;">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="images\logo.png" style="width: 116px; height: 36px;" alt="Cuda">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <p class="welcome-text">Hi there! We are the new kids on the block and we build awesome websites and mobile apps</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm">
                <a href="#">WORK WITH US!</a>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid services">
        <h1>Services we provide</h1>
        <hr />
        <p class="text-wrap">We are working with both individuals and businesses from all over the globe to create awesome websites and applications.</p>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row services_cards">
                <div class="card-deck">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images\flag.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Branding</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id a ipsam quae</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images\crayon.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Design</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id a ipsam quae</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images\gears.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Development</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id a ipsam quae</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images\rocket.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Rocket Science</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id a ipsam quae</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
    </div>
        <div class="container-fluid team">
            <h1 class="text-uppercase">Meet our beatiful team</h1>
            <hr />
            <p>We are a small team of designers and developers, who help brands with big ideas</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="mugshot rounded-circle mb-1 mx-auto" style="object-fit: contain; text-align: center;"></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Nadir Asgerov</h3>
                                <p class="job mb-2">CEO/Marketing Guru</p>
                                <p class="card-text mb-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure fugit nemo deleniti quidem enim similique molestiae expedita, incidunt!</p>
                                <ul class="contacts row mx-auto">
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\facebook.png">
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\twitter.png">
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\linkedin.png">
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\mail.png">
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="mugshot rounded-circle mb-1 mx-auto" style="object-fit: contain; text-align: center;"></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Nadir Asgerov</h3>
                                <p class="job mb-2">CEO/Marketing Guru</p>
                                <p class="card-text mb-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure fugit nemo deleniti quidem enim similique molestiae expedita, incidunt!</p>
                                <ul class="contacts row mx-auto">
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\facebook.png">
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\twitter.png">
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\linkedin.png">
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\mail.png">
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="mugshot rounded-circle mb-1 mx-auto" style="object-fit: contain; text-align: center;"></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Nadir Asgerov</h3>
                                <p class="job mb-2">CEO/Marketing Guru</p>
                                <p class="card-text mb-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure fugit nemo deleniti quidem enim similique molestiae expedita, incidunt!</p>
                                <ul class="contacts row mx-auto">
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\facebook.png">
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\twitter.png">
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\linkedin.png">
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\mail.png">
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="mugshot rounded-circle mb-1 mx-auto" style="object-fit: contain; text-align: center;"></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Nadir Asgerov</h3>
                                <p class="job mb-2">CEO/Marketing Guru</p>
                                <p class="card-text mb-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure fugit nemo deleniti quidem enim similique molestiae expedita, incidunt!</p>
                                <ul class="contacts row mx-auto">
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\facebook.png">
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\twitter.png">
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\linkedin.png">
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="base rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="images\mail.png">
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <script src="https:/code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application of Bootstrap's CSS framework has a lot of issues that are contributing to the inconsistencies that you're seeing:

- Jumbotron doesn't need `.container-fluid` applied, a simple padding application (`.p-*`) will apply the necessary padding to match `.container-*`.
- `.container` classes **need** their sibling classes (`.row`, `.col-*-*`) to properly align items.
- `.card-deck` is not meant to integrate with the Grid System. If you need more granular control of the deck you should apply the cards individually with `.h100` to manage the height.
- Is it a `<button>` or a `<a>`? You're using both and that's going to cause some issues.

If we correct the inconsistencies with your code and eliminate all of your custom CSS to ensure you're seeing a 'clean' Bootstrap layout it would look something like the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid p-3">
  <p class="welcome-text">Hi there! We are the new kids on the block and we build awesome websites and mobile apps</p>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">WORK WITH US!</a>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1 class="pb-2 border-bottom">Services we provide</h1>
      <p class="text-wrap">We are working with both individuals and businesses from all over the globe to create awesome websites and applications.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Begin Services Cards -->
  <div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col-12">
    
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/400x250" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Branding</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id a ipsam quae</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/400x250" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Design</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id a ipsam quae</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/400x250" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Development</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id a ipsam quae</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/400x250" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Rocket Science</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id a ipsam quae</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>     
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the above code, your Card Component already intelligently collapses because you're applying `.card-deck`.  The grid isn't necessary there unless you need really granular control...

Note: I've removed all of the additional, repeated elements since fixing the `.card-deck` once should illustrate how to apply that elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for answer. As I said I am beginner in bootstrap. But I cant understand. So the catds cousing this problem?

Comment: The way you were utilizing Bootstrap's grid-related classes were causing a lot of layout inconsistencies. I'd recommend really reading through Bootstrap's documentation and examples, especially with the Card Layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will consider this.

Comment: If you have any other questions feel free to ask! For an example of how you CAN use the Grid with Card I would point you to an answer I made the other day that utilizes that layout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738048/bootstrap-4-why-isnt-this-aligned-to-the-bottom/55747061#55747061

Comment: Ok I will look at that